# jqgrid datetime column sorting in 24 hour format

Tags: json, datetime, jqgrid

I am using a json object as follows from spring MVC to populate the jqgrid by using a json reader.

```
{
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "startTime": "Mar 4 08:00",
            "projectId": "Proj_001",
            "customerId": "Cust1",
            "divisionId": "Div1" 
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "startTime": "Mar 5 15:00",
            "projectId": "Proj_001",
            "customerId": "Cust1",
            "divisionId": "Div1" 
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "startTime": "Apr 14 22:00",
            "projectId": "Proj_001",
            "customerId": "Cust1",
            "divisionId": "Div1" 
        } 
    ]
}
```

I need to sort the

> startTime

column which comes in 24hour time format (as above in the json object). i tried do some workaround but still unable to succeed.

jqgrid code -

```
{name:'startTime', index:'startTime', width:90,align:"left",sorttype:'datetime',datefmt:'M d, Y at h:i',sortable: true,editrules:{date:true} },
```

i will not using AM/PM notation here. i saw in jqgrid.base.js it uses AM/PM notation to sort. can anyone please shed some light on this? i was unable to find any jqgrid example for using date with 24hour time format that will do sort. Thank you in advance.

my jqgrid code -

```
jq(function(){
    jq("#testgrid").jqGrid({
        url:"/getall.html",
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames:['Id','Start Time','Cust.Id','Div.Id','Proj.Id'],
        colModel :[
            {name:'id', index:'id', width:90,align:"left",hidden: true},
            {name:'startTime', index:'startTime', width:90, align:"left",
             sorttype:'datetime', datefmt:'M d h:i',sortable: true,
             editrules:{date:true}},
            {name:'divisionId', index:'divisionId', width:100,align:"left"},
            {name:'departmentId', index:'departmentId', width:120,align:"left"},
            {name:'projectId', index:'projectId', width:100,align:"left"},
        ],
        pager: '#testpager',
        loadonce: true,
        sortname: 'projectId',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: true,
        multiselect: true,
        //to hide pager buttons
        pgbuttons:false,
        recordtext:'',
        pgtext:'',
        gridview: true,
        caption: 'my JQGRID',
        jsonReader : {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            cell: "cell",
            id: "id"
        }
    });
    //toolbar search
    //jq("#testgrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar',
    //                       {stringResult:true,searchOnEnter:false});
});
```

Comment: Could you include (modify and append the text of your question) the full definition of jqGrid. If it is possible I recommend you to use only standard ISO date format (like 2011-03-25) in the JSON data and use `formatter:'date'` and `newformat` inside of  `formatoptions` to convert the data in the format which should be displayed.

Comment: I have used 'datefmt:'M d h:i'' and it is sorted correctly now. but when json returns 'null' for 'startTime' element it will not properly get sorted. so problem is not 100% solved yet.

Comment: If you find a bug, you should post it [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/). I recommend you to insert in the bug report full JavaScript code and test data which can be used to reproduce your problem. You posted only one line of the `'startTime'` column definition and to reproduce your problem one will have to write some code which will just took the time.

Comment: @Oleg sorry about my mistake. i added my grid code as well. i don't know whether it's a bug. i still think the error is on my side and i'm working on it. will walk through your advice. Thank you very much Oleg.

Comment: @Sam: I tried you code and it work without any problem. It works also if I use `null` for the 'startTime'. What is your current problem? If it will help I can post the URL to my working tests.

Comment: @Oleg:my current problem is when i set the 'startTime' to 'null' and click on sort , it displays the null row as the 2nd row of the grid.apart from that other dates are sorting correctly for 'asc' and 'decs'. if you can post your working URL it will be a great help. Thank you and i appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I try to reproduce your problem all seems working correct. See the demo live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Sam.htm). If you will sort by the "Start Time" column all work without any problem which I could see.

Comment: Thank you very much Oleg.now i am using the date with the year as you recommended and it's working fine now.i looked into your sample and it seems to be something wrong from my side. i will create the fresh jqgrid and compare to troubleshoot the real factor cause to me.Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sam: You are welcome! If you will have trouble you can describe the problem in the new comment or the new question and I'll try to help you.