# jqgrid json data type with spring mvc

Tags: json, jqgrid

I am new to jqgrid and I tried to simulate above code, but it is not working. In server side i have created class

```
public class TaskBean {
String orderId;
String realty;
String building;
String priority;
String action;
String assignee; // add getter/setter methods
}
```

TaskBeanList.java

```
public class TaskBeanList {
private String page;
private String total;
private String records;
private List<TaskBean> rows;
}
```

Spring Controller Code

```
@RequestMapping("/page4.htm")
public @ResponseBody TaskBeanList   getJQGridData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
System.out.println("xml data");
List<TaskBean> taskList = new ArrayList<TaskBean>();
   taskList.add(new TaskBean("Task1", "K-CY-329", "144", "G-3", "1", "Pending", "XYZ"));
    taskList.add(new TaskBean("Task2", "K-CY-356", "165", "A-10", "4", "Closed", "ABC"));
    taskList.add(new TaskBean("Task3", "K-CY-343", "768", "B-12", "3", "Pending", "IJK"));
    taskList.add(new TaskBean("Task4", "K-CY-786", "918", "F-9", "2", "Open", "PQR"));
    TaskBeanList tsklst = new TaskBeanList("1", "5", "20", taskList); 
    return tsklst; 
}
```

Client side JQGrid JS code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
jQuery("#list3").jqGrid({
autowidth: true,
datatype : "json",
url: "http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/page4.htm",
mtype: 'get',
colNames : ["Title","Order ID","Realty","Building",
        "Priority","Action","Assignee"],
colModel : [
{label: "Title",   name: "title",   index: "Title", jsonmap: "orderId"},
{label: "OrderID", name: "orderId", index: "OrderID", jsonmap: "orderId"},
{label: "Realty",  name: "realty",  index: "Realty",  jsonmap: "realty" },
{label: "Building",name: "building",index: "Building",jsonmap: "building"},
{label: "Priority",name: "priority",index: "Priority",jsonmap: "priority"},
{label: "Action",  name: "action",  index: "Action",  jsonmap: "action"  },
{label: "Assignee",name: "assignee",index: "Assignee",jsonmap: "assignee"}
],
sortname : "Title",
sortorder : "desc",
shrinkToFit: true,
viewrecords: true,
jsonReader : {
  root: "rows",
  page: "page",
  total: "total",
  records: "records",
  repeatitems: false,
  cell: "cell",
  id: "id",
  userdata: "userdata",
  subgrid: {root:"rows", 
        repeatitems: true, 
        cell:"cell"
      }       
}
}); });
```

Can any one help to resolve this? When I see jqgrid sample code, looks simple but i dont see any output. The output page is empty. Pls help to resolve.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the following tutorial first:

jqGrid and Spring 3 MVC Integration Tutorial at http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/jqgrid-and-spring-3-mvc-integration.html

You might find your answers from that tutorial or at least it will refine what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks chris, I have struck up in converting java object to JSON using jackson plugin. I am getting saxparser exception if i include  <mvc:annotation-driven /> to my dispatcher-servlet.xml. I have kept jackson jar in my classpath. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

@user669789 first of all go through the krams tutorial that chris has mentioned.i am also new to jqgrid but that tutorial and source helped me a lot.another alternative is use hard coded json values according to your jsonreader in the jqgrid and see if itz get populated. have a look on [this example by Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278139/jqgrid-datetime-column-sorting-in-24-hour-format.)

try to write it to the printwriter and see weather you can get the json output by invoking it through the URL

Answer (score 0):

In Controller you can try to convert list to Json.That Json value will directly bind to JQGrid if all column names matches

**Controller Class**

```
@RequestMapping("/page4.htm")
public @ResponseBody String getJQGridData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
System.out.println("xml data");
List<TaskBean> taskList = new ArrayList<TaskBean>();
   taskList.add(new TaskBean("Task1", "K-CY-329", "144", "G-3", "1", "Pending", "XYZ"));
    taskList.add(new TaskBean("Task2", "K-CY-356", "165", "A-10", "4", "Closed", "ABC"));
    taskList.add(new TaskBean("Task3", "K-CY-343", "768", "B-12", "3", "Pending", "IJK"));
    taskList.add(new TaskBean("Task4", "K-CY-786", "918", "F-9", "2", "Open", "PQR"));
    TaskBeanList tsklst = new TaskBeanList("1", "5", "20", taskList);
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    String result = gson.toJson(tsklst ); 
    return result; 
}
```

Download gson.jar and then try this

Its worked for me.You can also refer to the sample Project from here

http://www.jriyazahamed.blogspot.com/